# Trying to combine the rows having 3 columns same and 1 different column into one row javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to combine the the rows having same into one column.

Suppose my th are id,name

Suppose am having like

```
1  ram
1  raj
```

then I want output as

```
1  ram,raj
```

`ram,raj` should be displayed in text area

Am getting the data using youtube api

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:90%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>ram</td>
 <tr>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>raj</td>
 <tr>
```

Comment: Paste your code what you tried before....

Comment: How is the input data formatted?

Comment: @yash Am not able to understand how to combine because data is not from mysql if there is any clue I can try it

Comment: @motanelu am getting input data through youtube api so am echoing them to table

Comment: Post a sample data, post what you tried so far!

Comment: @sravyanaidu put your HTML table in Question....

Comment: @yash updated table in question

Comment: @motanelu updated table in question

Answer (score 0):

Give ID to your Table Like this:-

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="example" style="width:90%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ram</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>raj</td>
    <tr>
 </table>
```

And in your Jquery code you can get String Like this:-

```
            var str = "";
var table = $("#example");
table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'), examplestring = $tds.eq(1).text();

    if(str=="")
    {
        str = examplestring;
    }
    else
    {
        str = str + "," + examplestring;
    }

});

console.log(str);
});
```

Where str contains your string

Comment: I need to get if the first column is equal only

Comment: @sravyanaidu I don't understand what are you trying to get

Comment: two rows should be combined if they have the same id only but in the code given by they combine all if the id is not equal also